# Installing MagickWand for PHP on Ubuntu

Tags: php, ubuntu, installation, magickwand

I apologize in advance for the newb-ish question.

I'd like to install MagickWand for PHP (http://www.magickwand.org/) on my ubuntu server.  Is there a simple "apt-get install" command I can use?

The website tells me to install MagickWand by re-configuring PHP, but I would rather not if it's unnecessary--and I'm not even sure where the PHP extensions file is or how I'd find it (I've looked everywhere--I didn't install PHP from source, so maybe it doesn't exist??)

Thanks in advance for your help.  Hopefully there's a quick and easy answer to this.

Best,
Jake

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to install ImageMagick software which has the components you need:

sudo apt-get install imagemagick

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, Sathya.  I have in fact installed imagemagick (when I run the command you suggest, I get "imagemagick is already the newest version. 0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 85 not upgraded").  But when I try to use MagickWand in PHP, I get the following error: Fatal error: Call to undefined function NewMagickWand() in magickwand_test.php on line 7"

Comment: I figured it out -- I just had to follow the instructions more carefully... d'oh.  

1. Get the MagickWandForPHP stable version: 

    svn co https://www.imagemagick.org/subversion/MagickWandForPHP/branches/MagickWandForPHP-1.0.8 MagickWandForPHP-1.0.8

2. Go in to the folder that you just downloaded 

    cd MagickWandForPHP-1.0.8

3. Type

    phpize.
    /configure
    make
    make install

4. Go to your php.ini file (mine was in /etc/php5/apache2/) and add

    extension=magickwand.so


5. Restart apache